# 同じ文章で違う代名詞を省けますか？

Tags: て-form, parsing, pronouns, omission

どう長い文章を作るかが分かるようになりたいです。この間、日本語教師の動画を観ていたら、下の文が出てきました。これはまさに先生が言った話です。

> 10歳、11歳ぐらいときに、子供向けの英会話教室に通い始めて、通い始めた理由がその英会話教室に入会したら、ぬいぐるみがもらえるっていうキャンペーンをやっていて、
> 本当にそのぬいぐるみが欲しくて、母に『英語頑張るから』と言って、入会させてもらいました。

「～て」は繋がる行為でも繋がらない行為でも使われるらしいですね。例えば、動画の字幕は英語で書かれていて、その字幕に先生が自分のことを話すときも、英会話教室のキャンペーンを話すときもあっても、文頭から文末まで「～て」で繋がっているんですが、文の分析を確かめてもらいたいと思います。

①まず、先生は「子供向けの英会話教室に通い始めて」と言ったとき、最初に「～て」の文型で考えの連続を続けるつもりだったけど、途中で他のことを話すことにしてそのまま続けました。「通い始めてぇ…それで…あ、実は…」みたいな感じです。で、「子供向けの英会話教室に通い始めました。通い始めた理由が…」とも言い換えたら、同じ意味だと思いますか？この判断は合っていますか？

②日本語ではよく代名詞を省きますね。「ぬいぐるみがもらえるっていうキャンペーンをやっていて」と言ったとき、「彼らは」を省略しましたか？それなら、次の文でまた「私は」を使いましたか？つまり、「英会話教室に入会したら」と言ったので、間接的に誰の話かが分かるはずだから、代名詞を省いて色々な人について下のように話せますか？

「（私は）10歳、11歳ぐらいときに、子供向けの英会話教室に通い始めて、通い始めた理由がその英会話教室に入会したら、（彼らは）ぬいぐるみがもらえるっていうキャンペーンをやっていて、（私は）本当にそのぬいぐるみが欲しくて、母に『英語頑張るから』と言って、入会させてもらいました。」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence you have quoted is a disorganized and half-broken sentence that only happens when someone says something *as they are thinking*. I feel particularly uncomfortable with this sentence because it has no copula (だ/です) corresponding to (通い始めた)理由が. An educated person never constructs a sentence like this when writing carefully.

However, in speech, people often have to start a sentence before deciding how to finish it. You have to get used to sentences like this. I think this sentence can be explained in several ways:

- In casual speech, people often prefer て/で to です even at the end of a sentence (言いさし表現) to keep the listener's attention. When parsing a long sentence connected by many て, such as this one, it may be necessary to consider that a sentence has effectively ended after a て/で. See: [て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60762/5010)
- As you said, sometimes people even start another sentence in the middle of one sentence. It's called a parenthetical aside (See: [What does 人の手により in this sentence mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68179/5010)). In your case, it seems that the speaker suddenly wanted to start to describe a reason by saying 通い始めた理由が, but then failed to correctly conclude the parenthetical part by saying something like なんですけど.
- Even in serious writing, some people are not very good at matching a subject and a predicate correctly. See: [Sentence topic without grammatical function](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61152/5010)

As for the implied subjects, the subject of キャンペーンをやっていて is either the school itself or someone in the school. Something like this is very common, and this is not a problem of this sentence.

I made minimal changes to the original sentence. The following is still a little messy as written language, but is organized enough as conversational sentences. For example, an editor of an interview article would revise the original transcription to something like this. If you feel comfortable reading this one, don't worry too much about the remaining "broken" parts:

> 10歳、11歳ぐらいのときに、子供向けの英会話教室に通い始めまして。通い始めた理由が、その英会話教室に入会したら、ぬいぐるみがもらえるっていうキャンペーンをやっていた、というものなんですけど、本当にそのぬいぐるみが欲しくて、母に『英語頑張るから』と言って、入会させてもらいました。